# A local variable in an Angular template

Tags: angularjs

Here is the code I was *planning* to write:

```
<div ng-repeat="row in rows">
  <div ng-init="localVar = someComplicatedFunction(row)">
     {{localVar.someValue}}
     {{localVar.someOtherValue}}
  </div>
<div>
```

But here is the warning in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit):

> The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.

I don't understand what I am being told here.  How would I even ask the controller to do anything here without `ng-init`?

Comment: What is `rows` in this case? Where does its value come from?

Comment: putting `someComplicatedFunction()` in markup is going to be expensive anyway due to numerous digest cycles. Why can't you run it on data in controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the warning means is that ngInit is only appropriate to e.g. "rename" `$index` to a more appropriate name.

Apart from that you could use a controller as follows:

```
angular.module('yourModule').controller('RowCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.localVar = $scope.someComplicatedFunction($scope.row);
});
```

And then you could use it as follows in your template:

```
<div ng-repeat="row in rows" ng-controller="RowCtrl">
    {{localVar.someValue}}
    {{localVar.someOtherValue}}
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What it's trying to say is that the controller should be generally building up any values that you want to use.

Run your complicated function within your controller, store the result, and use that for your `ng-repeat`:

```js
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    function someComplicatedFunction(row) {
        return { someValue: ':-)', someOtherValue: ':-<' };       
    } 

    var rows = obtainRows();

    $scope.processedRows = rows.map(someComplicatedFunction);
}]);
```

```html
<div ng-repeat="row in processedRows">
   {{row.someValue}}
   {{row.someOtherValue}}
<div>
```